# Upper level imports python

Tags: python, python-import

I'm using python 3.6 and wondering why I can't import from  a package in a parent directory:

```
project_folder/
   folder_with_code/
         __init__.py
         a.py
         b.py
   examples/ 
         example_1/
             example.py
   tests/
         some_test.py
   execute_tests.py
```

In the example.py folder I want to import for example the `a.py` or `b.py` files, eg. `import folder_with_code.a`. I have tried using `..` and `sys.path.append` but with no joy.

Comment: Please have a look at the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#packages) first, how to create a package. `__init__.py` files should be in all sub directories

Answer (score 0):

If your current working directory is `project_folder/` then you should be able to import the code from your package like this:

**examples/example_1/example.py**

```py
import folder_with_code.a
```

So if your working directory is `project_folder/`, then your packages (folders with `__init__.py` files) will be recognized by the import mechanism of Python, and in that case your imports will be relative from working directory.

Comment: How about if the working directory is examples/example_1/example.py? Can you go backwards?

Comment: You can always append to your `PYTHONPATH` but I'd strongly recommend setting the cwd to your project root as that will save you from a lot of hassle and is the norm.

Comment: Another option would be to package your code and do a `pip install -e .`, that way any code could import it from the site packages if they are in the same environment. So you could try your examples locally from the `example` folder as well and later your users could just copy paste your code to try it in their environment.